# How can I get XCTest to run tests in a particular order?

Tags: xcode, xctest

I'm just starting to use Apple's new Xcode 5 unit testing framework.  I have low-level classes that I would like to test before testing higher level classes that utilize these low-level classes.  For instance I have to database control classes that use a special UUID class. It makes no sense to test the DB classes if I have a regression in the UUID system.  I would like to run the suite of UUID tests first.

Has anyone found a technique or practice with the XCTest framework to allow this?

Answer (score 11):

I have tried with success to name the test methods using a numeric scheme, like:

- -(void)test_1_myFirstTest
- -(void)test_2_mySecondTest
- ...
- -(void)test_n_myNthTest

It seems it works in the desired order, however it is maybe not guaranteed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: should be guaranteed, since they run in alphabetical order

Comment: @CommaToast Have you found any solution? I too crying with you now :(

Comment: @Confused Yes I did, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39602686/in-xcode-8-what-is-the-way-to-make-test-methods-run-in-a-particular-order-withi/39647132#39647132

Comment: @CommaToast Awesome you found a way in objective C, would you happen to know a way in swift?